# Good pseudoclassical JavaScript inheritance pattern?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

Reading 'Javascript The good Parts' from Crocksford, I've been in a quest to write some *efficient, readable and reusable* JavaScript code.
That's all I aim, and particularly like the Object's properties being public.

That being said, is there any particular **problem** or point of improvement to this **code?**

```
( function(){

    window.App = {}

    // define uma pessoa normal
    App.Person = function(name){
        this.name = name || "anon"
        this.iq = 100
        this.fortune_number = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)
    }

    App.Person.prototype.sayName = function() {
        return (this.name+"!")
    }

    App.Person.prototype.sayIQ = function() {
        return (this.iq)
    }



    // define um genio da humanidade
    App.Genius = function(name) {
        App.Person.call( this, name )
        this.iq = 9000
    };
    // inherits All methods from Pessoa
    App.Genius.prototype = App.Person.prototype

    App.Genius.prototype.solveNP = function() {
        return "eureka!"
    };

})()


var p = new App.Person('Jon')
console.log( "A Person:", p.sayName(), p.fortune_number, p.sayIQ() )
//-> A Person: Jon! 10 100

var g = new App.Genius( 'Eugenios' )
console.log( "A Genious:", g.sayName(), g.fortune_number, g.sayIQ(), g.solveNP() )
//-> A Genious: Eugenios! 7 9000 eureka!
```

I'm particularly unsure if this line `App.Genius.prototype = App.Person.prototype` is good, because I usually see prototyping after some *new instance*, like in [Mozilla Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model#section_12)

Comment: I'm, curious why you wrapped the code in an immediately executed anonymous function.
Because in this case it only means overhead because a new execution context at the end of the scope chain is created in which you run code which only has side effects on the window object.

Comment: I upvoted Jan's answer, since that points out the problem in your inheritance pattern. I wrote an article about things to look for when setting up JS inheritance, http://js-bits.blogspot.com/2010/08/javascript-inheritance-done-right.html

Comment: @PM5544 this is just a technique to keep any `var` created inside this scope only, and not thrown in the global scope. (in this particular case is useless since I'm not declaring any)

Comment: @Fabiano PS: Just pointing out something i think can be improved in the form of a question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no true inheritance in your code. You HAVE TO extend the prototype chain in order to have true (prototypal) inheritance.

```
// This is how it's done in JS
Child.prototype = new Parent();
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
```

This has the side-effect of executing the Parent constructor which can be bad in some cases (for instance if the constructor expects any parameters). You should use the following bit to do the inheritance.

```
var Fn = function () {}; // empty constructor, no side-effects
Fn.prototype = Parent.prototype;

Child.prototype = new Fn();
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing

```
App.Genius.prototype = App.Person.prototype
```

is not a good idea:

```
var Parent = function (name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Parent.prototype.greet = function (who) {
    alert(name + ' say hi to ' + who);
}

var Child = function () {
}

Child.prototype = Parent.prototype;

Child.prototype.shout = function (you) {
    alert('HEEEEY '+ you);
}

var c = new Child();
c.shout('Joe');

var p = new Parent('Joe');
p.shout('Jimmy');
```

*See this [in action](http://jsfiddle.net/ZkCr8/)*.

This alerts `HEEEEY Joe` and `HEEEY Jimmy`.

What happens is that both the parent and the child get the same `prototype` object. Effectively you overwrite the `prototype` of the parent.

Usually it's best to put an instance for the childs prototype:

```
Child.prototype = new Parent();
```

However, this has the problem that the `Parent`'s `name` param is missing and, more importantly, executes the constructor. Usually what is done is put an empty function in the middle. It's a good idea to wrap this in a utility.

```
var hasProp = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty, 
    extend = function(child, parent) { 
    # Copy the class-level attributes (static in Java)
    for (var key in parent) { 
        if (hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key]; 
    }
    # Create the middle man
    function ctor() { 
        this.constructor = child; 
    }
    # Use parent's prototype and DON'T modify it
    ctor.prototype = parent.prototype;
    # Assign an instance to child's prototype, so modifications
    # to it are not reflected up the inheritance chain
    child.prototype = new ctor;
    # Simple convenience attribute to know your super class
    child.__super__ = parent.prototype;
    return child;
};
```

Usage:

```
# Replace this
Child.prototype = Parent.prototype;
# with this
extend(Child, Parent);
```

---

### Or just use [CoffeeScript](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script) and it will *Do The Right Thing*™.

Comment: Many friends have been charmed by CoffeeScript, was just hoping to learn a pure way before going for it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I create pseudoclasses using a self made inheritance library:

```
      //Namespace, ie global. could be "MyNamespace.MyClass"...
Class( "MyClass", HisClass, /* List of classes to inherit from/interfaces to implement */, {

    MyClass: function( name ) { //Constructor
    this.name = name;
    }

    "final override sayHello": function(){ //there is no implicit overriding
    alert( "hello from " + this.name );
    },

    "static create": function( name ) {
    return new this( name ); //this refers to constructor in static method
    }
});
```

You would then instantiate that class:

```
var a = new MyClass( "john" );
```

or

```
var a = MyClass.create( "john" );
```

I have only implemented the pseudokeywords "final", "static" and "override". I don't know if it's good but it works for me. But as you can see, I am not worrying about prototypes at all there, so if you want to create a pseudoclassical library but have to use prototypes when you make classes, then it's not that pseudoclassical in my opinion.

Answer (score -1):

I would just add a private field:

```
var that = this;
```

and in all your methods, use `that` instead of `this`.

Comment: How is this relevant to the question?

Comment: Nope! Where would that line go? This cannot be used with the style that the OP has. The only place that could share a variable with all methods would be before you define the constructor, and at that point `this` is not going to point to an instance...

Comment: It's relevant because this isn't always "this"

Comment: @Juan - Yes you're right, due to function scope, it would not work. He'd have to declare it all in the person constructor.